# Use react-redux useSelector with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

When trying to use the new useSelector hook (see below example) of react-redux typescript gives an error that the function does not exist:

```
Module '"../../../node_modules/@types/react-redux"' has no exported member 'useSelector'.  TS2305
```

**Example**:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { Message } from "./Message"

export const MessageContainer = () => {
  const searchValue = useSelector((state) => state.search)
  return (
    <Message searchValue={searchValue} />
  )
}
```

**Used versions:** 
"react-redux": "^7.1.0-alpha.5"
"@types/react-redux": "^7.0.9"

Comment: Typescript has not updated yet. You're using `@types/react-redux` which has 7.0.9 version. These hooks were added in 7.1.0.

Comment: Since it's currently the latest version of the types, is there any workaround to import the function and avoid the error?

Comment: Apparently a temporary fix can be done by adding the module definition yourself: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/34913#issuecomment-493483068

Answer (score 0):

the code below took from redux doc itself about typescript
[typescript redux offical](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript)

```
interface RootState {
      isOn: boolean
    }

// TS infers type: (state: RootState) => boolean
const selectIsOn = (state: RootState) => state.isOn

// TS infers `isOn` is boolean
const isOn = useSelector(selectIsOn)
```

as it says before the hooks been added later but you better write Selector like this if you use the hooks